# android imageView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-xml

I'd like to do such thing.... There is a Relative layout with splash.PNG as a background.... there are five ImageViews: @drawable\1.png, @drawable\2.png, @drawable\3.png, @drawable\4.png and @drawable\5.png...

1-is clickable and visible;
2-5 - are invisible and clickable="false"

by clicking once Imageview 2 becomes visible but unclickable, and then by clicking all 2-5 appears, then by clicking last fifth time 2-5 again becomes invisible....

As for me, such construction works with one invisible ImageView:

```
    final ImageView iv36 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yabl3skr);
    iv36.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v33) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            final ImageView iv37 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.yab3);
            iv37.setVisibility(1);
            iv37.setClickable(true);
            iv37.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v33) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            iv37.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            iv37.setClickable(false);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Need any ideas how to do it in a good way with five imageViews?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I fully get it, but what I think you're saying is that you have five ImageViews that all perform conditional logic when clicked.  If that's the case, what I normally do is implement single OnClickListener for all of the images.  You can set an initial state on all of your images and then do a switch on the id of the View being passed to enable and show which ever views you want to show.

```
    final ImageView iv33 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv33);
    final ImageView iv34 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv34);
    final ImageView iv35 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv35);
    final ImageView iv36 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv36);
    final ImageView iv37 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv37);

    OnClickListener imageClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Initial state
            iv33.setClickable(false);
            iv34.setClickable(false);
            iv35.setClickable(false);
            iv36.setClickable(false);
            iv37.setClickable(false);

            iv33.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            iv34.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            iv35.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            iv36.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            iv37.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            switch(v.getId())
            {
            case R.id.iv33:
                // show and hide what you would like...
                break;
            case R.id.iv34:
                // show and hide what you would like...
                break;
            case R.id.iv35:
                // show and hide what you would like...
                break;
            case R.id.iv36:
                // show and hide what you would like...
                break;
            case R.id.iv37:
                // show and hide what you would like...
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    iv33.setOnClickListener(imageClickListener);
    iv34.setOnClickListener(imageClickListener);
    iv35.setOnClickListener(imageClickListener);
    iv36.setOnClickListener(imageClickListener);
    iv37.setOnClickListener(imageClickListener);
```

Comment: Thanks, I have changed your construction and it works fine... The noly thing - initial state is set up in xml in my project and with this change it works....

Comment: android:clickable="false"
    android:visibility="gone"